# unable to update the oracle DB using ExecuteNonQuery()

Tags: c#, oracle, executescalar

Please find the source code below. I am not getting any error but
 `_oracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` is going infinite - debugger is not moving to next line. I am able to update the data using Toad. I am stuck with this.

```
  public void UpdateNewResignationRequestInSynergy(string _employeeno, string _comment, string _changeby, string _changeddt, string _reason)
    {
        int rowsaffected = 0;
        string returnStatus;
        string _synquery = "";
        DateTime dtDate;
        _employeeno = "774647";
        _comment = "contract eand";
        dtDate = DateTime.Parse(_changeddt, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-CA"));
        _oracleCommand = new OracleCommand(_synquery, _synergyDb);
        _synergyDb.Open();
        _oracleCommand.CommandText = string.Format(@"update wipinfo.fms_resignation set str_comments = 'contract end' where STR_CONTRACTOR_ID = 774647");
        _oracleCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        try
        {
             _oracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();



        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
        _synergyDb.Close();

    }
```

Comment: Try `_oracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: sorry it was _oracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); only

Comment: Maybe your update statements hits a LOT of records and it takes a lot of time to process?

Comment: @StevenLemmens no only one record

Comment: @mjwills that was a typo error, i am using ExecuteNonQuery()

_employeeno ,_comment these parameters I will be using .as simple update query is not working can't add these parameters now.

Comment: Is _synergyDb some sort of global that stores the connection object?  You use it, but I don't see you initializing it.

Comment: @mjwills  if same query executed in Oracle client will 1 record with no time. no prob with query

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/5380747/34092 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/23696049/34092 help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [oracle ExecuteNonQuery freezes on ASP.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23687552/oracle-executenonquery-freezes-on-asp-net)

Comment: @mjwills thanks a lot....  this works i have not committed in my oracle developer.
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23687552/oracle-executenonquery-freezes-on-asp-net/23696049#23696049

Answer (score 0):

You have to stop the oracle server and start again( do not restart  it will not help you). I solved this problem by doing this process.